# One to One field Django Admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, one-to-one

*Edited to use a one-to-one field*

I'd like to add the area of a building to a django modeladmin.  The table structure is

```py
class Area(models.Model):
    id= models.IntegerField('Buildings', db_column='id')
    area=models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

class Buildings(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    auto_sf = models.OneToOneField(Area, db_column='id')
```

I know that I can access the area attribute by using

```
b=buildings.get(id=1)
print(b.area.area)
```

But I don't understand how to incorporate b.area.area into the modeladmin - since this doesn't work.

```
class AdminSection(admin.ModelAdmin):
        
    def area(self, obj):
           return obj.area.area

    fields=(('id','area'))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to be able to set the `area` from the `Building` admin, look into using [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin). If you just want to display the `area` on the change list page, use [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display). Incidentally, if this is really a one-to-one relationship you might be better off using a `OneToOneField` rather than a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: I've edited the question to use a one to one field.  I would prefer to  keep it all in the same admin, rather than using an inline, if possible, since the inline would require moving the fields around on the screen.

Comment: Shouldn't `Area` inherit from `models.Model`?

Comment: sorry, yes, I simplified the code for this example, and you are correct.

Comment: Ultimately, what I did was add the readonly attribute that was missing. readonly_fields = ('area')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated, you are looking to use an [inline model admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin), like so:

```
class AreaInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Area
class BuildingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (AreaInline, )
admin.site.register(Building, BuildingAdmin)
```

Also, your models should ideally have singular names, i.e. `Building`, to make the more semantic sense - e.g. A building has an area. Unless the `Buildings` object is literally managing multiple buildings per instance.

Comment: When I try this, I get an error: `'Area' has no ForeignKey to 'Building'`

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: The Foreign Key has to be in 'Area' not in 'Building'.

Answer (score -1):

As shown below, if **"Building" class** has **"models.OneToOneField()"** referring to **"Area" class** which means **"Building" class** has **the ForeignKey** referring to **"Area" class**:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Building(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    area = models.OneToOneField( # Here
        Area, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
```

Then, you can inline **"Building" class** under **"Area" class** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Area, Building

class BuildingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Building

@admin.register(Area)
class AreaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (BuildingInline, )
```

As shown below, if **"Area" class** has **"models.OneToOneField()"** referring to **"Building" class** which means **"Area" class** has **the ForeignKey** referring to **"Building" class**:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Building(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    area = models.OneToOneField( # Here
        Building, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
```

Then, you can inline **"Area" class** under **"Building" class** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Area, Building

class AreaInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Area

@admin.register(Building)
class BuildingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (AreaInline, )
```