# Display fields from one-to-one model

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a User model (stock django), linked with a `UserProfile` via a `OneToOneField`. Is it possible to display data from the `UserProfile` in the admin, when displaying users in tabular view?

I am doing:

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserprofileInline,)
    list_display = (
        'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff'
    )


# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

How can I extend the `list_display` parameter to specify fields belonging to the `UserProfile`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/163823/386221

Answer (score 1):

For example if you have an address field in **UserProfile** model then you can do like this

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserprofileInline,)
    list_display = (
        'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff','address'
    )

    def address(self,obj):
        return obj.userprofile.address
```

Comment: Ok, interesting: I need to proxy the properties then? Is it not possible to specify UserProfile properties directly in the `UserAdmin.list_display`?

Answer (score 0):

You can register your extended model 'UserProfile' to the admin site.
In that model, you can show your fields from OneToOneField User model.

Please check this out: 
[One to One Field Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209293/one-to-one-field-django-admin)

Comment: I do not want to edit, but to display the values from the related model, in the same table as the user details are displayed: the row will show both the user fields and the userprofile fields (since they are one-to-one related)